# Scrapy parse to pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

For example I want to crawl three similar urls:

```
https://example.com/book1
https://example.com/book2
https://example.com/book3
```

**What I want is in the pipeline.py, that I create 3 files named book1, book2 and book3, and write the 3 books' data correctly and separately**
In the spider.py, I know the three books' name which as the file name, but not in the pipeline.py
They have a same structure, so I decide to code like below:

```
class Book_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        # item handling
        yield item
```

Now, how can I do?

Comment: how do you know the "filename" or "book's name", because if you can set it as a spider parameter, the pipeline's `process_item` has the spider as argument, so you could get it inside `process_item` like `spider.filename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smith, If you want to know book name in pipeline.py. there are two options either you make a item field for book_file_name and populate it accordingly as you want. or you can extract it from url field which is also a item field and can access in pipline.py